# GridView TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a gridview populated with textbox that can format datetime using this code

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtDateTo"      
    Text='<%#Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("ByPassDateTo")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") %>' 
    Enabled='<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("ByPassDateTo").ToString()) 
      ? true
      : false) %>'   />
```

The code is working but the problem I'm facing is that if the textbox.text is populated with null values i get the error
 Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

Can someone pls tell me the proper way to do this.. Tnx!

Comment: The `TextBox` can never be `null`. `ByPassDateTo` can be `null` in database.

Comment: @TimSchmelter yup.. sorry what i mean is null from the db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use codebehind, in my opinion that's much more readable and maintainable:

```
protected void gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;  // if this doesn't work use the debugger to see the real type
        TextBox txtDateTo = (TextBox) e.Row.FindControl("txtDateTo");
        DateTime? byPassDateTo = row.Field<DateTime?>("ByPassDateTo");
        txtDateTo.Text = byPassDateTo.HasValue ? byPassDateTo.ToShortDateString() : "";
    }
}
```

It's also more efficient and less error-prone due to type safety and compile time check.

Answer (score 2):

You can use inline if condition same as you use for Enabled.

plz try below code:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtDateTo" Text='<%# String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("ByPassDateTo").ToString()) ? string.Empty : Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("ByPassDateTo")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") %>' Enabled='<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("ByPassDateTo").ToString()) ? true: false) %>'   />
```

Thanks

Comment: It's a `DateTime?` not a string.

Comment: if the value retrieved in **Eval("ByPassDateTo")** is null then during conversion it will give an error.

Comment: Hi Tim, I have edited my ans and also check it. its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should check whether value retrieved from database is null or not. You can try below code for the textbox :

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtDateTo" Text='<%# Eval("ByPassDateTo") == null ? string.Empty : Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("ByPassDateTo")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") %>' Enabled='<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("ByPassDateTo").ToString()) ? true : false) %>'   />
```